# Backbone.js change view variable without reinitalizing

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone.js app that I am developing (first one so forgive me if this is a silly question). I have a header view (background and a title). I have a model which updates the title depending on the view/template rendered. I also listening for a change and re-rendering the view to display the new title. This works however the entire view is re-rendered (I know why it is rendering the entire view again) but wondering if there is a way to just update the title?

Heading View:

```
var HeadingLabelView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: '.heading-label-wrapper',
   initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, "render");
      this.model.bind('change', this.render);
   },
   render: function() {
      var that = this;
      var template = _.template($("#heading-label-template").html(), that.model.toJSON());
      that.$el.html(template);
   }
});
```

Login View:

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: '.page',
   render: function() {
      pageHeading.set({ name: "Log In" });
      var that = this;
      var template = _.template($("#login-template").html(), { });
      that.$el.html(template).trigger('create');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by listening only on the change event for the name property of the model

```
var HeadingLabelView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: '.heading-label-wrapper',
   initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, "render");
      this.model.bind('change', this.render);
      this.model.bind('change:name', this.renderTitle);//listen to changes on the 'name' property
   },
   render: function() {
      var that = this;
      var template = _.template($("#heading-label-template").html(), that.model.toJSON());
      that.$el.html(template);
   },
   renderTitle: function(model,value,options) {
      //assuming your title tag can be located with 'heading-label-title' id, this will update the title only
      this.$("#heading-label-title").html(value);
   },
});
```

Check out the [Catalog of Build-in Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) on the backbonejs.org, you should be able to listen only to changes of a specific property of the model.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I will also check out the documentation more too.